# for loop not operating

Tags: c, for-loop, nested-loops

I came up with what I thought was a messy solution to an awkward (albeit standard) problem:
For a given user input, reverse the letters of the words

E.g:

> This is a standard test

becomes

> sihT si a dradnats tset

and not

> tset dradnats a si sihT

The heart of the matter is this piece of code

```
  while (!iscntrl(user_input[x])) // quit when new line is read
      {
        restart:
        x++;
        puts("first level test");
        if (user_input[x]==' ')
            {
            puts("second level test");
            for (i=x; user_input[i]!=' '; --i)
                {               
                reverse_words[k]=user_input[i];
                k++;
                puts("third level test");
                goto restart;
                }
            }
        }
```

(yes, I know, there is a goto in there :/ )

but the third level of the loop is never touched.

Presumably there is something completely wrong with `(i=x; user_input[i]!=' '; --i)` as a for loop parameter?

`x`, `i`, and `k` are all initialised as integers == 0 prior to the beginning of the first loop.

Comment: Factoring the reversal logic into a function might make such problems easier to debug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, your condition contradicts here:

```
 if (user_input[x]==' ')
            {
            puts("second level test");
            for (i=x; user_input[i]!=' '; --i)
```

You only enter if `user_input[x]` is space, but you loop as long as it's not equal to space.

Comment: Yes, I should have i=x-1 and then have it as i-- instead of --i....  When I encounter the end of a word, I want to progress back, putting the characters of the word that has just ended into the reverse_word array... without affecting x (the position in the input array). When the word that has been encountered has been entered into the reverse_word array, I want to go back where I left off (at x) ...

Comment: Although now that I think of it... I also need a condition to recognise when the first character of the input array is being read (i.e. for the very first word input) ... mildly awkward as strings don't begin with a null terminator :/

Comment: With your posted code, I can't understand the entire logic. But what I'd suggest is reverse the whole and then reverse each word.

Comment: 1.First do a plain reverse of the while line: `This is a standard test` to `tset dradnats a si sihT` 2. Then reverse each word: `sihT si a dradnats tset`.

Comment: Plain reverse is simple... but I don't see how it lends itself to the final result...?

Comment: 1. Read chars from start till you hit a whitespace. 2. Reverse the word once a space is hit 3. Continue to store all the whitespaces as before hitting any non-whitespace. 4. Repeat the same as long nul is not encountered. Example: Read `This` we hit a space now. Reverse it and store: `sihT` and cotinue to store spaces: `sihT ` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this section:

```
 if (user_input[x]==' ')
            {
            puts("second level test");
            for (i=x; user_input[i]!=' '; --i)
                {
```

In the first line, you've established that `user_input[x]==' '`.

A few lines later, you set up a loop that will run while `user_input[i]!=' '`.

However, you've set `i = x`... thus, in the first pass, you're requiring that `user_input[x]!=' '`... which you've already established to be false.

Thus, the inner loop will never run.